# Qt creator - dependencies - how to get qtlibrary to another machine

Tags: qt, distribute

I made my project in the QtCreator, released it and I wanted to distribute it to another machine where the QtCreator is not installed. (obviously) But when I am trying to run it, it does not work because it doesn't find files as libQt5Widgets.so.5 .. and so on, so I tried ldd command to find out which files are required, took them and put them to my Qt_Libraries folder, but I don't know how to put them to "system libraries" ..

I tried something like this but nothing .. 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/to/Qt_Libraries; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

I'm working with UBUNTU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use static linkig Qy library. Everything about it you can find here:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html